# How To get current date in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have XSLT 1.0 , I need to print current date and time in text file. and I am using visual studio to run XSLT file.

If anybody knows how to get current date time in XSLT 1.0 please let me know.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack over flow..can you please suggest how to edit this.

Comment: Thanks Daniel..Any suggestion to get the current date in XSLT 1.0..I am using visual studio to execute the XSLT which gives Output file as Text File

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried to do the same but not working..actually I am calling the same code from same my XSLT is it right process to execute that code from same XSLT